# Timing of IndexedDB requests and transactions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, indexeddb

I am reading up on IndexedDB (on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)). From what I gather, the usual pattern for doing practically anything is

1. create a request object,
2. add onsuccess, onerror and perhaps more callbacks
3. there's no 3.

The request then eventually does its thing and calls one of my functions (or settles a promise, if the wrapper is used). *I'm missing some kind of commitment step.* Given that the fulfillment of the request is asynchronous, does this mean it can happen on a different thread? If so, **what if it is really quick (or my code really slow) and manages to terminate between 1 and 2 before I've set my callbacks?**

Or is it that the requests will run on the same thread in idle periods? If so, I can imagine it happening that I overwhelm the request queue (say on a very low-profile device). How that would be signalled if callback is not an option (my function is still running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A write request such as put or add appends work to be done to the transaction on which it was created. A write request commits when its transaction commits. A transaction commits shortly after detecting there are no more requests to process.

It is a bit more complicated regarding what it means to commit, as I think Firefox and Chrome have different meanings, or did at some point in the past, where Chrome committed in memory and later flushed to disk, but Firefox did not commit until flushed to disk, or its backwards, sorry. Flushing to disk however might be pedantic/arbitray so I would not worry about this distinction. Especially if you are unfamiliar with things.

To detect when a transaction commits, listen for the complete event of the transaction.

To detect when a transaction rolls back due to an error and does not commit, listen for the error event of the transaction. There is also a weird note here, transactions do not possess an error property, only requests do. So the error event at the transaction level will correspond to the error from one of its requests.

To detect when a transaction finishes either successfully or not, listen for both the complete and error events.

JavaScript is single threaded. indexedDB manages threading and so forth for you. You do not need to worry about threads.

If your really slow code terminates during a request, the transaction will not complete successfully. The database will be in the same state as it was prior to starting the request, as if the request never happened.

If your really slow code terminates after the first request has completed but before a later request has completed in the same transaction, then the transaction will not complete successfully. A transaction only completes successfully when all of its requests complete successfully. Therefore the database will be in the same state as it was prior to starting the first request, as if if none of the requests in the transaction occurred.

If indexedDB is unable to fulfill a transaction due to some kind of performance pressure error then the transactions in question essentially do not commit and there is no durable state change. This would be raised as some kind of more general JavaScript error, or performance permitting, just a normal transactional error.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I guess the core of my question then can be pinned down to this bit in the beginning: `A transaction commits shortly after detecting there are no more requests to process`. Is the manner of this detection specified somewhere? My model situation could be that my really slow code enqueues an `add` requests, then proceeds to perform some calculation for 5 seconds and decides to put another `add` on the same transaction when the calculation is finished. I can't seem to quite match that to either of the situations you cover.

Comment: I mean, the transaction could have "detected" that there isn't anything more coming because of the delay. Or maybe it could? Ref count on the transaction object perhaps?

Comment: A transaction stops accepting new requests at the end of the current tick of the event loop in the browser. If you have slow code that is blocking, it extends the lifetime of the tick, no big deal. if you have non-blocking code that doesn't occur until the next tick of the event loop, then you get an error, you tried to add a request to a transaction that is no longer accepting request.

Comment: Excellent! Using these keywords (transaction, request, tick, event loop) I found a duplicate question with a spot-on answer also by you. That explains all so I'll mark this one as duplicate. I was really not aware of these internals so my searches prior to asking did not locate that one. Many thanks!